# 'AVV_ERR_PLUGIN_NOT_VALID' error in fastify

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, backend, fastify

i was trying to set up the environmental variables in my fastify - react app. why am I getting the 'AVV_ERR_PLUGIN_NOT_VALID' error for the following fastify code? thank you! :

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ 
    logger: {
      level: 'debug',
    }
  });
  
  console.log('hello from server.js 1 !');
  
  // setting up cors:
  const cors = require("@fastify/cors");  
  fastify.register(cors, { origin: "*" });
  
  // setting up environment variables
  const fastifyEnv = require('@fastify/env');
  const envSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    required: ['YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY', 'TESTVAR', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'JWT_SECRET'],
    properties: {
      YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY: { type: 'string' },
      TESTVAR: { type: 'string' },
      GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: { type: 'string' },
      GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: { type: 'string' },
      JWT_SECRET: { type: 'string' }     
    } 
  };
  const options = {
    confKey: 'config', 
    schema: envSchema,
    dotenv: {
      path: `${__dirname}/.env`,
      debug: true
    }
  };
  
  fastify.register(fastifyEnv, options);
  
  fastify.ready(err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('fastify.config at server.js: ', fastify.config);
  
    const fastifyJwt = require('@fastify/jwt');
    fastify.register(fastifyJwt, { secret: fastify.config.JWT_SECRET });
  });
  
  // setting up authentication:
  fastify.decorate('verifyJWTandLevel', (request, reply, done) => {
    done();
  }).decorate('verifyUserAndPassword', (request, reply, done) => {
    done();
  }).register(require('@fastify/auth')).after(() => {
    fastify.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/auth-multiple',
      preHandler: fastify.auth([fastify.verifyJWTandLevel, fastify.verifyUserAndPassword]),
      handler: (req, reply) => {
        req.log.info('Auth route');
        reply.send({ hello: 'world' });
      }
    });
  });
  
  // other setup...
  
  const videoRouter = require('./src/routes/videoRouter');
  fastify.register(videoRouter, { prefix: '/api/v1' });
  
  fastify.get('/', (request, reply) => {
    console.log('hello from server.js 5000!');
    reply.send({ hello: 'fastify server at 5000!' });
  });
  
  // Start function
  const start = async () => {
    try {
      await fastify.listen({
        port: 5000,
        address: '0.0.0.0'
      });
      console.log('Server is running on port 5000');
    } catch (err) {
      fastify.log.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  };
 
  fastify.ready(err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    start();
  });
```

complete error stack:

[FASTIFY] AvvioError [Error]: Root plugin has already booted
[FASTIFY]     at Boot._addPlugin (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:244:11)
[FASTIFY]     at Boot.use (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:216:25)
[FASTIFY]     at server. [as register] (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:40:14)
[FASTIFY]     at /home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/backend/server.js:42:13
[FASTIFY]     at manageErr (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/fastify/fastify.js:595:11)
[FASTIFY]     at exit (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/fastify/lib/hooks.js:110:5)
[FASTIFY]     at manageTimeout (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/fastify/lib/hooks.js:127:11)
[FASTIFY]     at _encapsulateThreeParam (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:562:7)
[FASTIFY]     at Boot.timeoutCall (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:458:5)
[FASTIFY]     at Boot.callWithCbOrNextTick (/home/totoro/vc_app/vc-app/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:440:19) {
[FASTIFY]   code: 'AVV_ERR_PLUGIN_NOT_VALID'

Comment: You need to add the `videoRouter` code. Anyway I would suggest to read my fastify book tbh (check my profile)

Comment: Dear @Manuel, i don't realize where is the problem and how it's related to the videoRouter  . I'll definitelyy read the book , thanx !!! const videoController = require('../controllers/videoController');

const routes = async (fastify, options) => {
  try {
    fastify.get('/captions/:videoId', (request, reply) => {
      videoController.getCaptionsByVideoId(request, reply, fastify);
    });
    console.log("fastify.config at videoRouter ", fastify.config) 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error at routing in videoRouter.js: ', error);
  }
};

module.exports = routes;

Comment: The main issue in the code is the ready method call. You are starting the server loading. The video route has the correct interface. Try to remove it

Comment: thank you, i removed the 'ready' call and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

When you call the [`ready` method](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#ready), the fastify server starts the boot.

After the boot you can't add decorators, hooks or plugins.

So, your issue can be replicated with the code:

```
const app = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

app.ready((err) => {
  app.register(function plugin (app, opts, next) {
    next()
  })
})
```

To solve it you need to remove the `ready` call.

Note that if you must await a plugin, you can [await the `register()` method](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Plugins#asyncawait).